# How to define IGNORE_DUP_KEY for table in EF Core code-first?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to define `IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON` for table in EF Core fluent entity configuration? Some annotation maybe? Can't seem to google anything for this. Is there maybe some annotation for these features of SQL Server?

Comment: Even if it's possible, why do you think this is a good idea? Better to change the index to non-unique

Comment: @siggemannen The semantics are different. `IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON` will prevent the row from being inserted at all, without throwing an error. A non-unique index is just not unique.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even know that. But it sounds like a bandaid solution to the real problem?